# Setting fields for new entities not working - EntityFramework

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

I've been coding non stop for the past 3 days, and now I ran into this. Setting 2 variables' text from textboxes. It's driving me mad. The code works when editing a project (fields aren't null), it just doesn't work when adding one (both fields null).

**What I have tried:-**
 I've tried using `.ToString()` method because it didn't work without either.

The part of the code that puzzles me:

```
proiect.titlu = projectTitleTb.Text.ToString();
proiect.descriere = projectDescTb.Text.ToString();
```

[image]

I need an answer to this badly as I'm running out of time and I cannot believe something like this is taking so much time.
EDIT:
[Before and after running the code for different case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HmKNi.png)

EDIT:
I think this might be caused by the differencies between object types: when editing, the object type is

{System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.proiecte_BFF409556A583A0C9542252D0669E388052C2AB6DA93A2EE4C48CBFB216E8114},

while when adding it's type is simply proiecte. The variable is stored in a viewstate:

```cs
proiecte proiect
    {
        get
        {
            if (ViewState["proiect"] == null)
            {
                return new proiecte();
            }
            return ViewState["proiect"] as proiecte;
        }
        set
        {
            ViewState["proiect"] = value;
        }
    }
```

This is what the object is assigned when editing:
    proiect = ProiecteDB.getById(id_proiect);
This is the function getById

```cs
public static dynamic getById(int id)
    {
        var db = new firma_itEntities();
        var query = (from p in db.proiectes
                     where p.id_proiect == id
                     select p).FirstOrDefault();
        return query;
    }
```

When the object is added and not edited, it doesn't query the database, so it just creates uses
    return new proiecte();

This is the class:

```cs
[Serializable]
    public partial class proiecte
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage",     "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public proiecte()
        {
            this.tasks = new HashSet<task>();
        }

        public int id_proiect { get; set; }
        public string descriere { get; set; }
        public string status { get; set; }
        public string titlu { get; set; }
        public string disponibil_resurse { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage",   "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<task> tasks { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Impossible to say without more code, but is your classes setters for titlu and descriere in order?

Comment: Yep... As i mentioned, the code works when the variables are predefined (with the values from the database), it just doesn't work when the values are null at first, but that shouldn't be a problem with C#

Comment: The code fragment you provided seems to be in order, so the problem is somewhere else. We can only guess where without more code.

Comment: If you put a breakpoint on the above code and inspect projectTitleTb.Text what do you see?

Comment: @LDJ You can see the values in the picture in watches.

Comment: The same value as the one in the watch

Comment: Remove textbox and assign some hardcoded string value to it. I hope your `set` is proper.

Comment: The new image you added is for the edit mode?

Comment: yes, it is...but nothing's really that much different. the object is initialized in both cases, the only difference is the properties are null when adding (which is normal)

Answer (score 0):

Ok apparently i fixed this by creating a new object in which I set the properties accordingly:

```cs
proiecte proiect = new proiecte
                    {
                        titlu = projectTitleTb.Text,
                        descriere = projectDescTb.Text,
                        status = "draft",
                        tasks = tasks
                    };
```

Answer (score -1):

I hope, you have set the property for the variables "titlu" and "descriere" in your project.

Could you please post the code for the above.

Comment: This is a comment and not an answer.

Comment: public string descriere { get; set; }
public string titlu { get; set; }
The classes were generated by entity framework, from a database model